# UITableViewController - Different number of cells for each section

Tags: uitableview, swift

I'm currently trying to load different entities from my CoreData model into one UITableView but under different sections. I've tried the following method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    var rows = 0

    if section == 0 {
        rows = crew.count
    } else if section == 1 {
        rows = aircraft.count
    } else if section == 2 {
        rows = batteries.count
    }

    return rows
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. It returns the first crew.count for every section. I should note that crew, aircraft and batteries are arrays of NSManagedObject.

Does anyone have any advice on how to implement what I'm looking for?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here are other methods I'm implementing for clarity..

```
var crew = [NSManagedObject]()
var aircraft = [NSManagedObject]()
var batteries = [NSManagedObject]()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let crewFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Crew")
    var crewError: NSError?
    let crewFetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(crewFetchRequest, error: &crewError) as? [NSManagedObject]
    if let crewResults = crewFetchedResults {
        crew = crewResults
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(crewError), \(crewError!.userInfo)")
    }

    let aircraftFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Aircraft")
    var aircraftError: NSError?
    let aircraftFetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(aircraftFetchRequest, error: &aircraftError) as? [NSManagedObject]
    if let aircraftResults = crewFetchedResults {
        aircraft = aircraftResults
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(aircraftError), \(aircraftError!.userInfo)")
    }

    let batteryFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Battery")
    var batteryError: NSError?
    let batteryFetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(batteryFetchRequest, error: &batteryError) as? [NSManagedObject]
    if let batteryResults = crewFetchedResults {
        batteries = batteryResults
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(batteryError), \(batteryError!.userInfo)")
    }
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    var rows = 0

    if section == 0 {
        rows = crew.count
    } else if section == 1 {
        rows = aircraft.count
    } else if section == 2 {
        rows = batteries.count
    }

    return rows
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
{
    return sectionTitles[section]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CrewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    switch indexPath.section.description
    {
        case "0":
            cell.textLabel!.text = crew[indexPath.item].valueForKey("name") as? String
            if crew[indexPath.item].valueForKey("pilot") as? Bool == true {
                cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Pilot"
            } else {
                cell.detailTextLabel!.text = " "
            }
            break;
        case "1":
            cell.textLabel!.text = "Aircraft"
            break;
        case "2":
            cell.textLabel!.text = "Battery"
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, your error will be elsewhere. Are you sure the array items are correct?

Comment: Yes I believe they're fine. Right now I have entries in 'crew' which all appear correctly and the other two have no entries so they shouldn't generate any rows for their sections but they still generate the same number of rows as for 'crew'

Comment: I've updated the OP with other methods I'm implementing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good, but you will need to set the number of section in tableview as well by implementing

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}
```

EDITED:

From the edited question I can now clearly see that your problem is with your data source

```
let aircraftFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Aircraft")
var aircraftError: NSError?
let aircraftFetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(aircraftFetchRequest, error: &aircraftError) as? [NSManagedObject]
if let aircraftResults = crewFetchedResults {
    aircraft = aircraftResults
} else {
    println("Could not fetch \(aircraftError), \(aircraftError!.userInfo)")
}

let batteryFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Battery")
var batteryError: NSError?
let batteryFetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(batteryFetchRequest, error: &batteryError) as? [NSManagedObject]
if let batteryResults = crewFetchedResults {
    batteries = batteryResults
}
```

`if let aircraftResults = crewFetchedResults` and `if let batteryResults = crewFetchedResults` will return crewFetchResults so all crew,aircrafts and batteries arrays are holding exactly the same elements. You must replace these lines with `if let aircraftResults = aircraftFetchedResults` and `if let batteryResults = batteryFetchedResults`. Hope I was clear enough

Comment: Yeah I'm also implementing that, sorry I left out some of my implementations for brevity.

Comment: I've updated the OP with other methods I'm implementing

Comment: Oh for goodness sake -.- So simple.. thanks very much, I appreciate it!